# How to measure High-Frequency inductance of inductor using an LCR meter?

Tags: inductor, inductance, lcr

I have a High-Frequency inductor available and I want to measure the inductance using the Rohde&Schwarz HM8118 LCR meter. If I change the frequency to 100kHz and voltage level to 1.5V (max) I get a value of 0.5 Henry which is way too high.

User manual of the LCR meter:

https://cdn.rohde-schwarz.com/pws/dl_downloads/dl_common_library/dl_manuals/gb_1/h/hm8118_1/HM8118_UserManual_de_en_06.pdf

The inductor is made of two ferrite cores as shown in for example here:

https://www.picclickimg.com/d/l400/pict/112230606209_/Ferrite-E-Core.jpg

How can I correctly measure the inductance (should get a value in microhenries) ?

**EDIT**:

Square wave signal of 100kHz is applied across the inductor (having no DC component). The measured inductance value also has a negative sign in front of it.

Comment: Choose f to match nearest fundamental (application) and AC couple with external DC and increase until L drops 10%. If SRF affects Z(f) (i.e. resonant) , L(f) reading will be invalid.

Comment: For my application I am generating a PWM signal with a frequency of 100kHz and after changing it from the default 1kHz I get this huge inductance value. Also, other settings are: BIAS = off, SPD = slow, OPEN = on, SHORT = on and LOAD = off. Any idea?

Comment: Use small signal and large Dc current external  It uses CC sine to measure Z .  I assume this is for DC application if not scratch that

Comment: Add  DC current and AC voltage hysteresis  causes  correct L reading without DC hysteresis gives too high H.  I think it has Ldc port for 100mA only, maybe 200mA. You may want to use lowZ plastic cap external and add X Amps DC to reduce L 10% ( just before saturation)

Comment: Is application Flyback or linear  i.e. DCM CCM

Comment: This DC current helps determines saturation point

Comment: Is this one winding of a transformer? If so, what to do with that secondary?

Comment: Just a single winding inductor

Answer (score 2):

Raising the frequency to 100 kHz could certainly mean that you are approaching the natural self resonant frequency and you will get stupidly high inductance values and sometimes, if the frequency is too high it will behave as a capacitor and your meter displays nF or pF.

The natural self resonance is brought about by the interwinding capacitance i.e. It becomes a parallel resonant impedance.

I'm not saying definite but I am saying there's a decent probability given the size of the core. I'd trust the inductance reading at 1 kHz but by no means is 1 kHz a panacea.

Comment: At 1kHz a get an even more unrealistic inductance value.

Comment: What did it measure and what do you expect it to read? Also how many turns and what AL value did you use to calculate L?

Comment: I expect it to read a value around the microhenries, around 10 turns